# AS3 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dagger/Provides

Tags: dagger-2, android-studio-3.0

Android Studio beta2 get dagger2 error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':arms:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dagger/Provides

The same error:
https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/843

Answer (score 0):

Got solution from there(api & implementation):

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html
http://blog.csdn.net/Marvinhq/article/details/73477128

Comment: so what **is** the solution?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations